# How to call below objective c category from swift class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIView (AEScaningEffect)


- (void) startScaningRepeatCount:(int)count;
- (void) startScaningRepeatCount:(int)count Duration:(int)duration;
- (void) startScaningRepeatCount:(int)count Duration:(int)duration HeightFactor:(float) factor;

- (void) stopScaning;

@end
```

Comment: Could you add some points to explain your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call it as simply as:

```
imgView.startScaningRepeatCount(2)
```

Or

```
imgView.startScaningRepeatCount(1000, duration: 2)
```

Or

```
imgView.startScaningRepeatCount(1000, duration: 2, heightFactor: 0.3)
```

Etc.

Remember to import your category's header from the project's bridging header.

Comment: I want to scan my image ,, that i'm calling from swiftclass... but in o∫j c the method is written like this ...[self.imgView startScaningRepeatCount:1000 Duration:2 HeightFactor:0.3];... how can i implement the same method in swift...

Comment: `imgView.startScaningRepeatCount(1000, duration: 2, heightFactor: 0.3)` is how you'd call this from Swift.

Answer (score 1):

You can call it like this:

```
var view = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)

view.startScaningRepeatCount(0)
view.startScaningRepeatCount(0, duration: 0)
view.startScaningRepeatCount(0, duration: 0, heightFactor: 0)
view.stopScaning()
```

Comment: I want to call something like this .. how can i call


[self.imgView startScaningRepeatCount:1000 Duration:2 HeightFactor:0.3];

Comment: self.imgView.startScaningRepeatCount(1000, duration: 2, heightFactor: 0.3)